# Facebook comments counter with current URL

Tags: html, facebook, elementor

I need make this work in an elementor text area.

I have multiple products pages and I want a counter for each one

An example of the facebook comment counter is this

```
(<span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="https://example.com/products/product1"></span>)
```

For a page with 2 comments the code do this: "Comments (2)"

Inside each page I have a facebook comment box and using shortcodes I can make it easily use the current url page.

But in the comment counter box I cant use shortcodes(just WYSIWYG), so I have to manually add the URL of the current page.

So what I want is **automaticaly** generate the current url inside of the comment counter code.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/y67x3921/

Comment: I didn't understand what your code do. Could you explain? Thanks

Comment: Using JavaScript you can build out the span element. Currently it does it when the page loads. Since there isn't much of an explanation I'm not sure what else you are looking for. If you can describe what you need more it might be easier to get help. what is `https://example.com/products/product001` is this the page of the website or another location? Every time you move to a new page is that what you want the data-href to say? Or does only a section of the URL have to change?

Comment: Here is an update version: https://jsfiddle.net/a5fvk20h/1/

Comment: Thanks Rick, I've updated the post

Comment: Doesn't seem like I have enough knowledge on the development tools you are using. I left an upvote in hopes it pushes your question higher up for someone with the knowledge to answer. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the nice education Rick. I don't know how but it worked, haha. But something is causing a bug in the page when I upload it. I'm trying to find it